# Find a certain url in a string Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string, for example:

```
[{'type': 'text/html', 'value': '<table> <tr><td> <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/comments/6dhhhj/waving_bear/"> <img src="https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/v5CaHQ_S-m4L5MUfX2a6ViwZWe2yvft_VyG8Iol0CJs.jpg" alt="Waving bear" title="Waving bear" /> </a> </td><td> &#32; submitted by &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/mexicanwave"> /u/mexicanwave </a> <br/> <span><a href="http://i.imgur.com/PMgfJSm.jpg">[link]</a></span> &#32; <span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/comments/6dhhhj/waving_bear/">[comments]</a></span> </td></tr></table>', 'base': 'https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers.rss', 'language': None}]
```

I want to extract the url that contains imgur.com in it from this string.

What's the simplest way to do that?

Comment: 1. That's a dictionary not a string. 2. If you want to extract something from HTML, have you considered an HTML parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myList = [{'type': 'text/html', 'value': '<table> <tr><td> <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/comments/6dhhhj/waving_bear/"> <img src="https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/v5CaHQ_S-m4L5MUfX2a6ViwZWe2yvft_VyG8Iol0CJs.jpg" alt="Waving bear" title="Waving bear" /> </a> </td><td> &#32; submitted by &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/mexicanwave"> /u/mexicanwave </a> <br/> <span><a href="http://i.imgur.com/PMgfJSm.jpg">[link]</a></span> &#32; <span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/comments/6dhhhj/waving_bear/">[comments]</a></span> </td></tr></table>', 'base': 'https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers.rss', 'language': None}]

for msg in  myList[0]['value'].split():
  if 'imgur.com' in msg:
    print(msg)

#href="http://i.imgur.com/PMgfJSm.jpg">[link]</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using XML/HTML parser is a proper way for manipulating xml/html documents/fragmets:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

data = [{'type': 'text/html', 'value': '<table> <tr><td> <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/comments/6dhhhj/waving_bear/"> <img src="https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/v5CaHQ_S-m4L5MUfX2a6ViwZWe2yvft_VyG8Iol0CJs.jpg" alt="Waving bear" title="Waving bear" /> </a> </td><td> &#32; submitted by &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/mexicanwave"> /u/mexicanwave </a> <br/> <span><a href="http://i.imgur.com/PMgfJSm.jpg">[link]</a></span> &#32; <span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/comments/6dhhhj/waving_bear/">[comments]</a></span> </td></tr></table>', 'base': 'https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers.rss', 'language': None}]

parser = etree.HTMLParser()  # creating parser instance
html_data = etree.parse(StringIO(data[0]['value']), parser)  # parser is fed with html data
url = [a.attrib['href'] for a in html_data.findall(".//a") if 'imgur.com' in a.attrib['href']]

print(url)
```

The output:

```
['http://i.imgur.com/PMgfJSm.jpg']
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Beautiful Soup. As you already have an HTML code as string. Refer to following code snippet. Now that you have all anchor tags, you can further look for the substring "imgur.com" from theor hrefs and get that particular link.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = your_list[0].value
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
result = soup.find("a")
```